# Android Button background Image changes back to state in XML

Tags: java, android, image, button

I have a simple soundboard which uses Buttons to represent the sounds. When a sound button is clicked. The background image is changed using the view.

```
Button butt = (Button)view;
butt.setBackgroundResource(buttons_on[media]);
```

`buttons_on` is a `int[]` representing the drawables of the buttons.

This all works perfect, **but** I also use a `FragmentActivity` to create a paged App. The App has 4 different pages which you can swipe through. When I change a button using the above code and swipe two pages to the right and than swipe back. The image of the button has changed back to it's default defined in the page.xml.

How can I prevent this behavior?

- change the Buttons to `ImageButtons` and setting the src?
- somehow prevent the page from reloading

Comment: Button ass = funny; // butt = ass, ya know?

Comment: Yeah I know :-) next time I call my button ass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that you should look at how to use a StateListDrawable. It will simplify your approach.

Comment: So I can add the "on" image in my XML? Or can I only use this programmatically?

Comment: Yes, you can: see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for reference